# C++ Template instancing with mutual reference

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Is there a way to allow two or more templates instanciations to mutually refer to each other ?

Example :

```
/* invalid C++ */
/* we suppose MyTemplate1 and MyTemplate2 are declared */

typedef MyTemplate1<MyInstance2> MyInstance1;
typedef MyTemplate2<MyInstance1> MyInstance2;
```

I suppose there is none, still asking just in case I missed something.

Adding more precision, I want to achieve such a construction :

```
/* invalid C++ */
#include <iostream>

template <typename typeT> struct MyStruct1 {
  static void print(unsigned i) {

    std::cout << "MyStruct1 : " << i << std::endl;
    if (i > 0) {
      typeT::print(i - 1);
    }
  }
};

template <typename typeT> struct MyStruct2 {
  static void print(unsigned i) {
    std::cout << "MyStruct2 : " << i << std::endl;
    if (i > 0) {
      typeT::print(i - 1);
    }
  }
};

/* of course this is invalid, since you can't reference MyInstance2
before it is declared */
typedef MyStruct1<MyInstance2> MyInstance1;
typedef MyStruct2<MyInstance1> MyInstance2;

int main() {

  MyInstance1::print(5);
  return 0;
}
```

output should be :

```
MyStruct1 : 5
MyStruct2 : 4
MyStruct1 : 3
MyStruct2 : 2
MyStruct1 : 1
MyStruct2 : 0
```

Please note I'm not trying to achieve a similar output, but a similar construct, where two (or more) templates instances refer to each other
with as few as possible additional code : it shall be easy to do mutual reference instantiation. However, for the implementation code of the two templates, I don't care if they are complicated.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You can't typedef something that doesn't exist. A typedef is just an alias for another type. But in your example there is no actual type refered.

Comment: @super that's the reason why I put a comment saying "invalid C++ code". I supposed that the "MyTemplate1" and other stuffs were sufficiently explicit to let people suppose the template would be declared before. Thank you for pointing our, I'll add the precision then.

Comment: Could you show what you expect the output of this program to be?

Comment: @cigien edited the post to add output :)

Comment: Ok, I guess my next question is, why do you want to do this? Seems like you could achieve the same result in other easier ways.

Comment: @cigien Oh, sorry, I should have precised that ^^ I'm implementing a recursive descent parser building library and I thought It would be fun to allow describing the syntax of the parsed language (and create the parser) using only compile-time stuffs. This is the reason why I want it to be as lightweight as possible when it comes to instanciation... Maybe I should precise that in the post as well ?

Comment: @cigien For now the best I can think of is something passing by a context and enums or other values used for referencing between instances. I'll try to post an example of it once I got it a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that at least gives the correct output. If it's also a viable solution for your use case is not very clear though but maybe it can at least help you clarify your question a bit more.

```
#include <iostream>

template <template <typename> typename TemplateT> struct TemplateType {
    template <typename typeT>
    static void print(unsigned i) {
        TemplateT<typeT>::print(i);
    }
};

template <typename typeT> struct MyStruct1 {
  static void print(unsigned i) {

    std::cout << "MyStruct1 : " << i << std::endl;
    if (i > 0) {
      typeT::template print<TemplateType<MyStruct1>>(i - 1);
    }
  }
};

template <typename typeT> struct MyStruct2 {
  static void print(unsigned i) {
    std::cout << "MyStruct2 : " << i << std::endl;
    if (i > 0) {
      typeT::template print<TemplateType<MyStruct2>>(i - 1);
    }
  }
};

typedef MyStruct1<TemplateType<MyStruct2>> MyInstance1;

int main() {

  MyInstance1::print(5);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks quite interesting ! I'm not sure if I prefer this version or mine actually... But that is only aesthetic matters, I'll probably mark your answer when I've fully analyzed and understood it, would you mind explaining a bit how is it built ?

Comment: @FelixBertoni It's using [template template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), so we can pass `MyStruct1` and `MyStruct2` without specifying their template parameters and breaking the cyclic dependency between them. `TemplateType` is just a wrapper to achieve that, and it has another template function that instatiates the template template parameter with whatever type is passed to it.

Comment: Oh, I see, I had a bit of hard time figuring out how you were calling the MyStructX function without instancing it, but the actual instancing is done in the template template (btw isn't it mandatory to have "class" after template template , instead of "typename ?"). I seems your answer is too specific for me, as it would be fairly hard to implemenent it for any combination of parameters, and would feel a bit unintuitive (not symetrical actually). Yet I'll mark your answer as accepted as I think it answers better to my question than mine x)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use class forward declaration:

```
template<typename T> class M
{
    static int foo(int i) { return i ? T::foo(i - 1) : 0; }
};
struct A;
struct B;

struct A : M<B>{};
struct B : M<A>{};
```

Not same code exactly but you have recursion.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but that's not what I am looking for ^^ I could maybe use it but I am afraid it will not solve my problem at all, my goal is to avoid having to declare new classes/structs ^^ However I will consider it, maybe I can take some inspiration from it to have my stuff work x)

Comment: @FelixBertoni Then its impossible, because you declare alias, and alias is self referencing:
`using MyInstance1 = MyStruct1<MyStruct2<MyInstance1>>;`
You need indirection to break this loop.

Comment: sadly that's what I thought... Well, I'll wait a bit to see it someone comes with an elegant way to do the thing or something close x)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a satisfying construct, which involves using a tierce struct acting as a context to declare subs elements. It isn't forcibly the best solution for anyone, and I will probably have to adapt it a bit more to fit my very need, but here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename K, typename T> struct TypePair {
  typedef K key;
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename Context, typename P0, typename... PN> struct TypeMap {
  template <typename K> struct get {
    typedef typename std::conditional<
        std::is_same<typename P0::key, K>::value,
        typename P0::type::template actual<Context>,
        typename TypeMap<Context, PN...>::template get<K>::type>::type type;
  };
};

struct TypeNotFound {};

template <typename Context, typename P> struct TypeMap<Context, P> {
  template <typename K> struct get {
    typedef
        typename std::conditional<std::is_same<typename P::key, K>::value,
                                  typename P::type::template actual<Context>,
                                  TypeNotFound>::type type;
  };
};

/* defining a context to link all classes together */
template <typename... TN> struct Context {
  template <typename K> struct Access {
    typedef typename TypeMap<Context<TN...>, TN...>::template get<K>::type type;
  };
};

/* templates we want to cross ref, note that context is passed as a parameter*/
template <typename ContextT, typename Id2> struct MyStruct1Actual {
  static void print(unsigned i) {

    std::cout << "MyStruct1 : " << i << std::endl;
    if (i > 0) {
      ContextT::template Access<Id2>::type::print(i - 1);
    }
  }
};

template <typename ContextT, typename Id1> struct MyStruct2Actual {
  static void print(unsigned i) {
    std::cout << "MyStruct2 : " << i << std::endl;
    if (i > 0) {
      ContextT::template Access<Id1>::type::print(i - 1);
    }
  }
};

/* wrappers to not have to always pass context when instancing templates */

template <typename type> struct MyStruct1 {
  template <typename ContextT> using actual = MyStruct1Actual<ContextT, type>;
};

template <typename type> struct MyStruct2 {
  template <typename ContextT> using actual = MyStruct2Actual<ContextT, type>;
};

/* Enum and dummy id, could simply use Enum actually, but using classes a Id
can prove to be more elegant with complex structures, expecially as it could be
used to automatically create pairs instead of having to precise Id */

enum Ids : int { Struct1, Struct2 };

template <Ids id> struct Id {};

// instancing all stuff withing context
// clang-format off
typedef Context<
            TypePair< Id<Struct1>, MyStruct1< Id<Struct2> > >,
            TypePair< Id<Struct2>, MyStruct2< Id<Struct1> > >
        > Ctx;
// clang-format on

typedef Ctx::Access<Id<Struct1>>::type S1;

int main() {
  S1::print(5);
  return 0;
}
```

Shortening names an giving more meaning than Context or TypePair will be mandatory, but the idea is here.

Comment: Even if this clarifies a bit what you're looking for your original question is still logically flawed and makes very little sense.

Comment: I kind of agree on that, It was really hard to formulate what I need ^^